# JustGage not defined after upgrading to angular 8

Tags: angular, justgage

After upgrading my apps from angular 7.2 to 8.2. the angular2-just-gage module([link](https://github.com/emn178/angular2-justgage/tree/master/src/app)) that i used throwing error.
First, is about "eve not defined", i tried upgrading raphael from version 2.2.7 to 2.2.8. But then it throw another error

> justgage.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: JustGage is not defined
>       at Object../node_modules/justgage/justgage.js (justgage.js:8)

I have tried updating JustGage and raphael module to latest version but still throwing the same error. Is there anyone who also encouter this issue and has the fix?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I have it working in angular 8.2.4 
I'm using these versions of the libraries...

"justgage": "^1.3.5",
"raphael": "2.2.8"

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, by setting "allowJs : true" in tsconfig.json file.